# Divs overlapping in chrome

Tags: jquery, html

My divs are overlapping in chrome(latest version), they are fine in firefox and amazingly enough, internet explorer. I made a real quick and simplified jsfiddle so you can see what I mean, if opened with google chrome you can see it overlapping. Anyone know what is going on? I tried putting in a 'clear' div but didn't seem to do anything. I'm a beginner so please bear that in mind. Thank you.

http://jsfiddle.net/QXz8P/7/

[image]

```
<div id="container">
<div id="thumbnails">
                    <div class="web" id="art1">
                        <img src="http://www.warrenphotographic.co.uk/photography/bigs/03534-Silver-tabby-cat-white-background.jpg" id="img1"/>
                        <div class="caption1">
                            <p id="thumbnailTitle">Title</p>
                            <p id="thumbnailSubtitle">SUBTITLE</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="graphic" id="art2">
                        <img src="http://www.southbham.cats.org.uk/uploads/images/pages/cat-stalking-crop.jpg" id="img2"/>
                        <div class="caption2">
                            <p id="thumbnailTitle">Title</p>
                            <p id="thumbnailSubtitle">SBTITLE</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="web" id="art3">
                        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d4/Cat_March_2010-1a.jpg" id="img3"/>
                        <div class="caption3">
                            <p id="thumbnailTitle">Title</p>
                            <p id="thumbnailSubtitle">SUBTTLE</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="illustration" id="art4">
                        <img src="http://media.npr.org/assets/img/2012/09/20/stripey-kitty-d1332c13945e17c5add3810e5ca39c269af872b8-s6-c10.jpg" id="img4"/>
                        <div class="caption4">
                            <p id="thumbnailTitle">Title</p>
                                <p id="thumbnailSubtitle">SUBTITLE</p>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="graphic" id="art5">
                        <img src="http://adam1cor.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/cat1.jpg?w=300&h=300" id="img5"/>
                        <div class="caption5">
                                <p id="thumbnailTitle">Title</p>
                                <p id="thumbnailSubtitle">SUBTITLE</p>
                            </div>
                    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    width:80%;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
    padding:5ex;
}
div #art1, #art2, #art3, #art4, #art5 {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

div img {
    opacity:  0.5;
    height: 70%;
}

.caption1, .caption2, .caption3, .caption4, .caption5, .caption6, .caption7, .caption8 {
    margin-top: -5px;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    height:40px;
}

.caption4 {
    margin-top: -4px;
}

#thumbnailTitle {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    color: #a5a4a4;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin:0px 0 10px 0;
}

#thumbnailSubtitle {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    color: #a5a4a4;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin:-10px 0 50px 0;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

div img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#thumbnails div#art4 {
    width: 40.4%;
}
```

Comment: Which divs are overlapping?  (I cannot access jsfiddle)

Comment: I added a quick picture. The divs (.caption1, .caption2, .caption3) are overlapping the lower divs (#art4 & #art5). Or I guess it is more like the 'caption divs' being underlapped by the 'art divs', as the upper caption divs aren't moving, the art divs are moving underneath. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to baseline your code, there were so many non best practices used it was just easier for me to refactor the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/QXz8P/10/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="thumbnails">

        <div class="art">
            <img src="http://www.warrenphotographic.co.uk/photography/bigs/03534-Silver-tabby-cat-white-background.jpg" />
            <div class="caption">
                <div class="title">Title1</div>
                <div class="subtitle">SUBTITLE1</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="art">
            <img src="http://www.southbham.cats.org.uk/uploads/images/pages/cat-stalking-crop.jpg" />
            <div class="caption">
                <div class="title">Title2</div>
                <div class="subtitle">SUBTITLE2</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="art">
            <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d4/Cat_March_2010-1a.jpg" />
            <div class="caption">
                <div class="title">Title3</div>
                <div class="subtitle">SUBTITLE3</div>
            </div>
        </div>        

    </div>

    <div class="thumbnails">

        <div class="art">
            <img src="http://media.npr.org/assets/img/2012/09/20/stripey-kitty-d1332c13945e17c5add3810e5ca39c269af872b8-s6-c10.jpg" />
            <div class="caption">
                <div class="title">Title4</div>
                <div class="subtitle">SUBTITLE4</div>
            </div>
        </div>          

        <div class="art">
            <img src="http://adam1cor.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/cat1.jpg?w=300&h=300" />
            <div class="caption">
                <div class="title">Title5</div>
                <div class="subtitle">SUBTITLE5</div>
            </div>
        </div>  

    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {}

.thumbnails  { overflow:hidden; display:block; }

.art {
    width:100px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.art img {opacity:0.5; width:100%;  }

.art .caption {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}

.art .caption. .title{
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    color: #a5a4a4;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.art .caption .subtitle {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    color: #a5a4a4;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".art").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).find('.title').css("background-color", "yellow");
    $(this).find('.subtitle').css("background-color", "yellow");
    $(this).find('img').css("opacity", "1");
}).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).find('.title').css("background-color", "transparent");
    $(this).find('.subtitle').css("background-color", "transparent");      
    $(this).find('img').css("opacity", "0.5");
});
```

This should get you closer to a more dry solution of what your were going for.

Comment: That seems to work okay in chrome. Thank you for simplifying the javascript too, what I wrote looks insane next to it. I'm still learning so I hope seeing my awfully messy code didn't annoy you too bad. Thank you!

Comment: I was wondering, it is possible and okay to have multiple classes on one element right? There were some classes I added in for a js image filter..it would be okay to add them back in?

Comment: Yep, multiple class names is ok.  I stripped some stuff out to make it less complex while I was wrapping my head around it.  Take the code I posted and build it back up to what you need.  Feel free to keep posting any questions you have about this code.

Comment: Thank you. Managed to get the filter working okay http://jsfiddle.net/QXz8P/14/ (just thought i'd show you incase you had any better ideas)...had to remove the thumbnails div because it was making them stack instead of being side by side. But now it's working great now, thank you! I just have one more question, I put the title & subtitle in 'p' elements before, you took them out, is it okay to have text without them always being in an element? It's not considered bad or anything?

Comment: Yep, the way you were using <p>'s was fine, I was just having a bit of problems styling them initially so I stripped them out to divs.  It's valid to put them back in.  Great to see your jsfiddle working well.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `padding` seems to help.

```
.clear {
    clear: both;
    padding-top:5ex;
}
```

Comment: It fixes it on chrome but then on firefox and ie the padding gets applied and there is a big gap.